# How do I get parentheses around my variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing one of my first assignments and I can't find out how to put parentheses around a variable when I go to print it.

I've tried
(xs)
{xs}
[xs}
But none get parentheses around it

```
(print)("Hello user! Welcome to the program!")
 name = input("What is your name?")
(print)("Hello", name)
x = input("What is your favorite number?")
y = int(x) // 2
xs = str(x)
ys = str(y)
z = ("Did you know that half of your favorite number" + ' ' + xs + ' ' + 'is' + ' ' + ys + '?')
```

print(z)

For the 2nd to last line of code I want it to say Did you know that half of your number (5) is 2?

## 5 is just an example number but I want it in parentheses!

Comment: Put second last line as `z = "Did you know that half of your favorite number" + ' (' + xs + ') ' + 'is' + ' ' + ys + '?'`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and follow a good tutorial to learn the language.Your code has far too much parenthesis in it. Read about string formating here: https://pyformat.info/ and google python f-string  if you are indeed on python 3.6+  - if you simply googled "how to print a number in a string python" you would have gotten thousands of solution to this problem. Tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  .. printing starts where strings are explained: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: I don't understand how the question could have been asked. OP **already knew** how to put **spaces** around the variable; putting parentheses works the same way, just typing parentheses instead of spaces in the actual string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like so:

```
z = ("Did you know that half of your favorite number" + ' (' + xs + ') ' + 'is' + ' ' + ys + '?')
```

Comment: better to use `str.format()`

Comment: of course, I'm just modifying his code.. it's easier for him/her!

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add the pharentesis in the right place, something like this:

z = ("Did you know that half of your favorite number" + ' (' + xs + ') ' + 'is' + ' ' + ys + '?')

Answer (score -1):

I am not exactly sure if that is what you need but you just have to concat `"("` and `")"` around your variable.

```
>>> y = "number"
>>> print ( "(" + y + ")" )
(number)
```